# migrating from Spring 2.5 to Spring 3.0.5

Tags: java, spring, migration

There was method `setWrappedInstance` in `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapper` in 2.5.6 and was removed in 3.0.0. As i am in the process of migrating my project from 2.5 to 3.0 I get errors. I investigated and the implementation class `org.springframework.beans.BeanWrapperImpl` still has the method `setWrappedInstance` implemented.

below is the piece of code from my project which is causing trouble.

```
public FieldComparator(String fieldName, Class clazz) {
    _fieldName = fieldName;
    _bw = new BeanWrapperImpl(clazz);
}    

public int compare(Object o1, Object o2) {
    if (o1 == null && o2 == null) return 0;
    else if (o1 == null) return -1;
    else if (o2 == null) return 1;
    // otherwise
    _bw.setWrappedInstance(o1);
    Comparable v1 = (Comparable) _bw.getPropertyValue(_fieldName);

    _bw.setWrappedInstance(o2);
    Comparable v2 = (Comparable) _bw.getPropertyValue(_fieldName);
    return NullsLowComparator.INSTANCE.compare(v1, v2);
}
```

So would it be ok if I just replace `_bw` implementation with `BeanWrapperImpl`. I am in the learning stage and I believe that spring strongly suggests to use interfaces rather than implementation classes itself.

Is this change against standard practices or can I just move on with the simple change?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `BeanWrapper.setWrappedInstance` method was marked as deprecated in Spring 2.5, and removed altogether in 3.0. Unlike deprecations in the JRE (which never get removed), deprecated APIs in Spring do get removed, so you're well advised to avoid them.

The [2.5.6 Javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapper.html#setWrappedInstance%28java.lang.Object%29) for `setWrappedInstance` says:

> Deprecated. as of Spring 2.5, in favor of recreating a `BeanWrapper` per target instance

In other words, instead of reusing instances of `BeanWrapper`, you should create new `BeanWrapperImpl` instances as required. There's no performance penalty for this - the `BeanWrapperImpl` [javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html) says that it "Caches introspection results for efficiency."

So replace this:

```
_bw.setWrappedInstance(o1);
Comparable v1 = (Comparable) _bw.getPropertyValue(_fieldName);
```

with this:

```
Comparable v1 = (Comparable) new BeanWrapperImpl(o1).getPropertyValue(_fieldName);
```

and get rid of the `_bw` field altogether.

> I believe that spring strongly suggests to use interfaces rather than implementation classes itself

As a general rule of thumb, yes. However, try to apply some practicality to this. Your use of `BeanWrapperImpl` is restricted entirely to internal implementation detail of your comparator, so there's no real harm in using it directly. If your comparator were to expose the `BeanWrapper` in a public method signature, for some reason, then that would be best done using the interface rather than the implementation.

Comment: +1 for the good explanation. I would favor using the PropertyAccessorFactory as suggested by the javadoc, though. Your answer would be perfect if it mentioned it. If you edit it, I'll remove mine.

Answer (score 1):

Given that it's your code that instantiates the bean wrapper, and that it's instantiated using `new BeanWrapperImpl()`, I don't see how it could fail if the field is of type `BeanWrapperImpl` rather than `BeanWrapper`.

However, [the javadoc](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.0.5.RELEASE/api/org/springframework/beans/BeanWrapperImpl.html) states:

> NOTE: As of Spring 2.5, this is - for almost all purposes - an
>   internal class. It is just public in order to allow for access from
>   other framework packages. For standard application access purposes,
>   use the
>   PropertyAccessorFactory.forBeanPropertyAccess(java.lang.Object)
>   factory method instead.

I would thus use what the javadoc suggests to use.